# Как сделать задержку на секунду при перерисовке Bitmap?

Tags: java, android

Есть:

```
ImageView ivPct;
Bitmap bitmap;
Paint p;
Canvas canvas;

ivPct= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_pct);

bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

Далее в цикле будет меняться цвет у bitmap, но надо сделать так цвет менялся с периодом в секунду.

```
int[] clr = new int[] {Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA};
    for (int i = 0; i < clr.length; i++) {
        p.setColor(clr[i]);
        canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 50, p);
        ivL.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        .......
    }
```

Comment: Я про андроиды ничего не знаю, но там же, наверное, тоже работает `Thread.sleep(1000);`? Стандартный Java API там в полном объеме доступен?

Comment: для того чтобы применить Thread.sleep(1000); наверно надо как-то выделить в поток задачу и делать паузу потоку? Попробую. Я просто хотел как-то проще это сделать.

Comment: Нет, ничего не нужно. Только заключить его в `try -- catch`: `try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception x) {}`. А проще мне трудно представить, куда еще проще  :)

Comment: Если нет других потоков, которые могут влиять на этот, то `sleep()` исключений не вызовет, поэтому пустой `catch` тут допустим. С нормальной ява-машиной так, по крайней мере. Про андроид я бы отдельно уточнил этот момент.

Comment: я попробовал, но не прокатило. При запуске, на экран сразу выводится фигура с последним цветом и все. Действия цикла нет. Нет перерисовки экрана.

Comment: В Андроиде есть две особенности: главный поток "усыплять" нельзя и изменять UI из фонового потока тем более. Тут нужен либо `Handler`, либо `View.postDelayed()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Особо не редактировал. Вставил из своего кода.

---

```
 Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {

                                            try {
                                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                                            }

                                            h.sendEmptyMessage();

                                    }
                                };
                                Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
                                thread.start();
```

---

```
  final Handler h = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    //Перерисовка Bitmap

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Пример отлично работает!

Comment: А как теперь остановить поток? Пробовал thread.stop(); но тогда приложение "падает".

Comment: Я этот поток никак не останоавливал. Возможно его мусорщик сам потом удаляет. Но я в этом не уверен.